# rails 3 embed video

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to embed youtube video.

in the videos db table, i have field called "link".This contains the link of the video.

In Controller Videos, there is just empty method def vidlist, since i'm just trying to display single video. 
I have vidlist.html.erb:

```
<blink>
<h1>Vidlist</h1>  

<object width="640" height="385">  
<param name="movie" value="<%= Video.first.link %>">  
</param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>  
<embed src="<%= Video.first.link %>"   
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"    width="640" height="385"></embed></object>  
</blink>
```

the link contains this string:http://www.youtube.com/v/KgmeL_xuB0I?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&autoplay=1
In routes .rb, i have uncommented the default route matching. 
Then, i started server.Entered localhost:3000/Videos/vidlist

The browser doesn't display anything at all.
and there's nothing in the console too when the server is running

Comment: hi, is only this page not working or all pages?

Comment: It works when I substitute the link into the source code you pasted. Are you sure the source code looks correct when the page finally renders to html?

Comment: On a stylistic note, putting something like Video.first.link into your views runs counter to the MVC approach. You are mixing controller logic into your view layer. You should set a variable in your controller like @first_video = Video.first, and then render <%= @first_video.link %> in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using html_safe on the link?  This will help ensure that you don't have issues with escape chars etc.